# Qt application failed to compile

Tags: qt, ubuntu, compilation, qt5

I just installed Qt5 and armed with "C++ GUI Programming with QT 4 (2nd edition)" i tried to compile a very app code goes like this:
-test.pro :

```
SOURCES += \
  main.cpp
QT+=widgets
```

and main.cpp :

```
#include <QApplication>
#include  <QLabel>

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    QApplication app(argc,argv);
    QLabel * label = new QLabel("hello world");
    label->show();
   return app.exec();
}
```

Here are the errors :

```
19:45:21: Running steps for project test...
19:45:21: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
19:45:21: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 
g++ -Wl,-rpath,/opt/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/gcc -Wl,-rpath,/opt/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/gcc/lib -o test main.o   -L/opt/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/gcc/lib -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [test] Error 1
19:45:21: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project test (kit: Desktop Qt 5.2.0 GCC 32bit)
When executing step 'Make'
19:45:21: Elapsed time: 00:00.
```

I'm using ubuntu 13.10 x86.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install OpenGL on your machine. It is missing and your make file needs it to build the project("-lGL missing").

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's not working even if you have already installed OpenGL. Then try to use:
`sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev`